# ValueError when converting a loop to vectorized format using np.where

Tags: pandas, numpy, for-loop

Getting the following error when using min, max function inside a np.where condition.

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I want to convert a 'for' loop into faster calculation so I am trying to switch my calculation using 'np.where' function.

Original working for loop code

```
for p in range (1,len(curve_details)):                       
      curve_details.loc[p,'coupon_after']=max(floor,min(ceiling, 
      curve_details.loc[p-1,'coupon_after']                                                       
      + max(move_cap_down, min(move_cap_up,                                                          
      curve_details.loc[p,'coupon_before']                                                          
      -curve_details.loc[p-1,'coupon_after']))))
```

New code I am trying

```
curve_details['coupon_after']=np.where(curve_details.index>0,
                             max(floor,min(ceiling, 
                             curve_details.loc[curve_details.index- 
                             1,'coupon_after'] + max(move_cap_down, 
                             min(move_cap_up,                       
                  curve_details.loc[curve_details.index,'coupon_before']
                              -curve_details.loc[curve_details.index- 
                             1,'coupon_after'])))),int_rate)
```

I want to speed up my for loop and hence have switched to the 'np.where' function. What can I change in my code to remove the value error right now?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bare `max` or `min` on arrays and scalars. Try using `np.clip`. I cannot show it in your code as I don't have a sample data. But a simple example:

```
x = np.arange(10)
cap = 6
low = 3
np.clip(x, low, cap)

# is equivalent to (and much better than):
np.array([max(low, min(cap, i)) for i in x])
```

Comment: I found another function np.fmax and np.fmin that give me the output of max and min. However, I am not able to structure my output correctly as I first need the current index value when np.where is getting executed and based on that need previous row value from (Index-1) . My syntax of curve_details.loc[curve_details.index- 1,'coupon_after'] gives me a series instead of just the previous row value while execution of np.where.